# Connect fb/gmail/yahoo/openid with CodeIgniter dx-auth

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, openid

Does anyone have advice on how to add Facebook Connect functionality for this library? Should I just dig into the source and add my own functions, or is there a more graceful way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work this out by combining dx_auth and a3m. The solution involves twiking the a3m to use dx_auth tables.